# How to self-draw a line with SMIL animation (not CSS)

Tags: animation, svg, smil

I'm wondering how to accomplish on an SVG [this CSS self-drawing effect](http://codepen.io/MyXoToD/pen/FcxuL) within the `<animate>` SMIL tag. Instead of using the css animation I would use something similar to this:

```
<line fill="none" stroke="#BBBBBB" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="19.69" y1="75.671" x2="19.69" y2="175.79"/>
<animate xlink:href="#first-line" attributeName="stroke" from="transparent" to="#BBBBBB" dur="0.5s" begin="0"  />
```

However, I can not make it work. What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than accessing the line by id and the line having no id there's not much wrong with your animation.

I've also increased the duration and changed the colour to make it clearer it's animating.

```html
<svg>
  <line id="first-line" fill="none" stroke="#BBBBBB" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="19.69" y1="75.671" x2="19.69" y2="175.79"/>
<animate xlink:href="#first-line" attributeName="stroke" from="transparent" to="red" dur="2.5s" begin="0"  />
  </svg>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, it was the id thing :) I guess it always helps a second look in the code when you've spent too much hours in front of it.